# How can I test the String.fromEnvironment method?

Tags: dart

How do I test that "flavorString" is "dev" if dart-define=FLAVOR=dev?

I need to know how to test values that depend on dart-define.

```dart
const flavorString = String.fromEnvironment('FLAVOR');
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use `const` with the `fromEnvironment` constructors.

Do:

```dart
const String flavorString = String.fromEnvironment('FLAVOR');
// ...
  if (flavorString == "dev") doSomething();
```

Or just do it in-place, since constants are canonicalized anyway:

```dart
  if (const String.fromEnvironment('FLAVOR') == "dev") {
    doSomething();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  How can I unit test the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with "test flavorString"?
++++